# UNC error on a powershell workflow

Tags: rscript, powershell-workflow

When I run the following powershell workflow :

```
Function Start-LocalRScript {
  Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]$Name)
  $ScriptPath = "C:\Exploration.RScripts"
  $RScriptExePath = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe"
  $scriptPath = Join-Path -Path $ScriptPath -ChildPath $Name
  & $RScriptExePath $scriptPath
}

Workflow Get-RScriptWorkflow {
  Start-LocalRScript script1.R
}
```

I get the following error but I still get the result of the R script:

```
Rscript.exe : '\\srvuser01\profil\myUser\Documents' At Get-RScriptWorkflow:2 char:2
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified ('\\srvuser01\profil\myUser\Documents':String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : [localhost] 
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.  
[1] "from script 1"
```

But when I run the command `Start-LocalRScript script1.R` there is no error. It seems that the workflow is trying to access the local path of my user that is in the network for the RScript.exe even though I specify where RScript.exe is on the script `Start-LocalRScript`. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

instead of call operator (`&`) use `Start-Process` with `-WorkingDirectory` set to proper working directory.